# Finding marginal CDF from joint CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $d$ financial losses $L_1, . . . , L_d$ have the joint distribution
function
$$F(x_1,..x_d)=exp(-(\sum_{j=1}^d x_j^{-\theta})^{1/\theta}$$
where $\theta \in [1,∞)$ and $x_1,...x_d \in (0,1)^d$.

What are the marginal distributions and inverse marginal distributions $F_1,...F_d$ of $F$?
I tried something intuitively according to [page 5 of this paper] (http://www.caee.utexas.edu/prof/bhat/ABSTRACTS/generalized_Gumbel_copula.pdf), but I am dont know if it is even close to being correct
$$F_1,.., F_d(x)=exp (-x_j)$$
$$F_1^{-1},.., F_d^{-1}(x)=-ln(u_j)$$